# AS3: How do I start a parent's timer?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function in a child that is supposed to start the timer in the parent class. The code to do so is:

```
MovieClip(this.parent).Investment1Timer.start();
```

But when it tries to do that, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

I can access the parent's functions and variables just fine, but I can't start any of its timers.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a scope issue, and Investment1Timer in the parent is private.

It should be :

```
public var Investment1Timer:Timer;
```

If you don't specify public or private, it will default to private and will not be accessible outside of that class code.

You should also verify that `this.parent` is not null and is actually a MovieClip or inherits from MovieClip.

I find the best way to investigate this kind of issue is by running in debug mode as you can then just check the variables involved to pinpoint what is null. Debugger is your friend!

I should also note that it's possible that you have declared Investment1Timer, but you did not create the instance, therefore it is still null ?

Comment: Also note that unless `this.parent` actually _is_ a MovieClip (or child thereof), or can be treated as such, the cast will return null.

Comment: He seems to indicate that he can access the properties/methods of the parent. But yeah, if it's not a MovieClip, that would be an issue too.

Comment: Indeed. It could also be that `this` is not added as a child to anything, and thus leaving `this.parent` as null.

Comment: I can access the parent's variables and functions with MovieClip(this.parent), so I'm pretty sure the parent is a movieclip.

Comment: Did you create the Investment1Timer instance in the parent, prior to this call ? That would be one reason why you might get a null error. I've added that as a thing to check in my answer.

Comment: The timer gets created in the parent class before the child is made.

Comment: It gets declared ? or did you create the instance ? ie `Investment1Timer = new Timer(500, 1);`